# How to design database for polymorphic relationships

Tags: database-design, polymorphic-associations

I have the following scenerio:

- There are some categories
- Each category has attributes
- An attribute could be of free text or collection of options
- There is a product which is assigned to category which needs to store values/options of attributes

How can a model be made without any repetition, and which correctly addresses the polymorphic nature of attributes?

Comment: Is the free text attribute can't be an option and become a collection with only one option ?

Answer (score 2):

I would design a meta-data/value based model, as:

[image]

Or, where formality is enforced,

[image]

Being `AttributeCode` and `ValueCode` unique, textual, human-readable identifiers, alongside the corresponding `AttributeId` and `ValueId`.

For instance, the hypothetical meta-attribute length, physically stored with `AttributeId = 1`, would (should!) be referenced in specific queries as `AttributeCode = 'LENGTH'`.

(of course, `AttributeCode` and `ValueCode` could compose the PKs... but I personally prefer PKs columns to be integer-only)